# heartbeat doesn't work on virtual interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, heartbeat, interface

I try to use vertual interface as broadcast for heartbeat(bcast in ha.cf).
When I try it I see this message in syslog:

```
May 23 12:17:26 Ubuntu2 heartbeat: [1107]: ERROR: glib: Error setting socket option SO_BINDTODEVICE: No such device
May 23 12:17:26 Ubuntu2 heartbeat: [1107]: ERROR: make_io_childpair: cannot open bcast eth1:0
```

But when I try use physic interface it work.

My ifconfig:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6c:46:05  
          inet addr:192.168.1.162  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe6c:4605/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1061 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:69886 (69.8 KB)  TX bytes:67058 (67.0 KB)

eth1:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6c:46:05  
          inet addr:192.168.1.62  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:120776 (120.7 KB)  TX bytes:120776 (120.7 KB)
```

Servers are pingable from each other from all interfaces. 
How I should setup my heartbeat to use this virtual interface?

Answer (score 2):

You... don't.  Heartbeat needs a physical interface to bind against.  If you're specifying a virtual interface because you want to use that interface's IP as the source address for your broadcasts, I believe you're out of luck -- there's no indication of a source address config option in [the ha.cf docs](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Ha.cf).